# Why do I get invalid number from this query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I get "ORA-01722: invalid number" from this query:

```
INSERT INTO OLD_MATCHES 
(ID, LEAGUE, WEEK, MATCH_DATE, HOME, AWAY, HOME_GOALS, AWAY_GOALS, HOME_BET, DRAW_BET, AWAY_BET, LEAGUE_SEASON)
VALUES
(OLD_MATCHES_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 240, 11, '26-02-2016', 'Chelsea', 'Arsenal', 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 'Premier league');
```

I looked at this explanation at Oracle FAQ:

An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number. Valid numbers contain the digits '0' through '9', with possibly one decimal point, a sign (+ or -) at the beginning or end of the string, or an 'E' or 'e' (if it is a floating point number in scientific notation). All other characters are forbidden.

But it didn't make sense to me.

sequence script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE FOOTBALL.OLD_MATCHES_SEQ
  START WITH 12
  MAXVALUE 999999
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  NOORDER;
```

Table script:

```
CREATE TABLE FOOTBALL.OLD_MATCHES
(
  ID             NUMBER                         NOT NULL,
  LEAGUE         NUMBER,
  WEEK           NUMBER,
  MATCH_DATE     DATE,
  HOME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  AWAY           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  HOME_GOALS     NUMBER,
  AWAY_GOALS     NUMBER,
  HOME_BET       NUMBER(5,2),
  AWAY_BET       NUMBER(5,2),
  DRAW_BET       NUMBER(5,2),
  LEAGUE_SEASON  NUMBER
)
```

Comment: Also, '26-02-2016' is a very strange way to format dates in sql. '20160226' is the norm for date-only values, and '2016-02-26 00:00:00.000' is the norm for values that include time components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the sequence. According to your table definition, `league_season` is a number field; you're trying to insert a string, `'Premier league'`.

You might need to change the table definition, but it looks more likely you're expecting to have a season number in there, probably a year:

```
INSERT INTO OLD_MATCHES 
(ID, LEAGUE, WEEK, MATCH_DATE, HOME, AWAY, HOME_GOALS, AWAY_GOALS, 
  HOME_BET, DRAW_BET, AWAY_BET, LEAGUE_SEASON)
VALUES
(OLD_MATCHES_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 240, 11, TO_DATE('26-02-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY'),
  'Chelsea', 'Arsenal', 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2015);
```

---

Also '26-02-2016' is not a date, it's a string. Either use an ANSI [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) like `date '2016-02-26'`, or use `to_date()` with a suitable format mask as I have above. Don't rely on implicit conversion and NLS settings. That isn't causing this error, but it will cause you a problem one day.

Answer (score 2):

> An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number. Valid numbers contain the digits '0' through '9', with possibly one decimal point, a sign (+ or -) at the beginning or end of the string, or an 'E' or 'e' (if it is a floating point number in scientific notation). All other characters are forbidden.

You need to replace your `OLD_MATCHES.LEAGUE_SEASON` to `Varchar2` type

or change your query where you insert number as `LEAGUE_SEASON`

```
INSERT INTO OLD_MATCHES 
(ID, LEAGUE, WEEK, MATCH_DATE, HOME, AWAY, HOME_GOALS, AWAY_GOALS, HOME_BET, DRAW_BET, AWAY_BET, LEAGUE_SEASON)
VALUES
(OLD_MATCHES_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 240, 11, '26-02-2016', 'Chelsea', 'Arsenal', 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1);
```